# Wordpress get_template_part based upon custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress theme with 100s of different template parts - ideally I'd like to be able to specify which template part to load based upon the value of a post's custom field.  i.e. if post's field value is `ABC` then get_template_part `ABC-template.php`. I'm using Advanced Custom Fields to specify the fields.

To get the field value you normally use:

```
<?php the_field('field_name'); ?>
```

I've tried something along the lines of

```
<?php $var = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'field_name', true);
    if ($var == '')
    { }
    else { get_template_part( "subdirectory/' . $var . '", "form" );} ?>
```

but this didn't work. Any ideas on retrieving the custom field value and then loading the relevant template part using get_template_part?

I'm aware I could in theory achieve this using the in_category function - but thought that having to cycle through 100's of "if post in_category ABC load ABC template, if post in_category DEF load DEF template" each time a post loads might slow the website down a bit?

Thank you so much in advance, really appreciate any help you can offer :)

***Edit: I've since worked it out (trial and error, I'm rubbish at PHP!)***

You need the following:

```
<?php
$fieldname = get_field('fieldname');
get_template_part('subdirectory/' . $fieldname ); ?>
```

If you have ABC-DEF stored in the custom field, this will then load the template in subdirectory/ABC-DEF.php

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: Does it work if you hard-code the template name? If so `var_dump( $var )` and see what did you get from the db.

Comment: Thanks for your help - It works fine if I hardcode the template name - I just need the PHP code to automatically insert the custom field value into the template name.  I've tried editing the code examples at https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/ but without much success - they all output the value of the custom field (ABC etc) but I can't get the PHP to insert that value within the get_template_part - sorry I'm not that good with PHP - I can usually configure scripts to work with what I need, I just don't have the ability to write from scratch.  Thanks guys